# Is this a good practice when using url parameters and php token authentication?

Tags: php, html, authentication, url, token

I am developing a small application for invoicing. The app itself has different views (dashboard, clients, invoices, company data...), and all data is stored in JSON files (it is needed to do this way, because of the requirements). The app is protected with password, but I would like to add more security parameters.

For changing, adding, or deleting data, what I've done is to create a php file (*master.php*) in which, apart of check whether the user is authenticated or not, I run a different method depending on the '*action*' argument of the GET request (modifying the JSON files depending on the request performed).

In order to protect from someone entering the url (http://whatever/master.php?action=deleteInvoice&invoice=3) and delete an invoice, for instance, I thought about adding a control parameter (a time-based token), generated in php when the page is load, like this:

```
http:...&token=<?php echo hash('md5', date("m.d.y-H").'salt'; ?>
```

getting the new url: http://whatever/master.php?action=deleteInvoice&invoice=3&token=*token*

This hash is generated for each hour, I mean, it is the same during the same hour in the same day. The fact is that if someone would be able to know the url to delete an invoice, it would be invalid after an hour.

The main purpose of this is, for example, if an authenticated user enters a url of the browser history (intentionally or unintentionally) and the data becomes inconsistent.

Then, in the *master.php*, I would do the following:

```
if ( $_GET["token"] != hash('md5',(date("m.d.y-H")."salt")) ){
    header( "Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."&error=time-exceeded" );
    exit;
}
```

that would return to the page where the user was, showing an error of *request time exceeded*.

Am I doing things properly? Is there any better way of proceed with this problem?

Comment: if you already have users that have to login, why not simply send the an auth-token (unique per user) along each request?

Comment: @Jeff But what I want to avoid is the fact that an authenticated user can enter an url again and perform some operation. My idea was to restrict the url to be workable only during 1 hour, for instance.
If I provide auth-token for the user, the same user could perform the operation by entering the link later in his browser, and I only want that the operation will be performed if the url has been entered because a link click in the application, not a link in a web browser. I don't know if I am explaining myself.

Comment: my way to go here would be to introduce a athorisation system, that checks if a specific user is allowed to edit/delete/update specific items. So you could have several levels of user rights.

Comment: If it's only about time (user is allowed to work/edit for a certain amount of time) you could still do that via an user-auth-token that expires after an hour. (as you usually have them expired after a week or month to be re-authenticated)

Comment: Yes I think your last reply is the good one for me. I am going to do it that way. Hope it works. Thanks @Jeff